# Azure- Not offered in the Region of your subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

When I try to create VDI on Azure, on the 'Choose Size' page I see 'Not offered in the Region of your subscription' against all the VM types. Do we really have Region for Azure subscription? How does it differ from Azure Region?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because region availability, within a subscription, is a customer service / billing issue (billing support is free, and available through the portal).

Comment: You'll need to open a ticket and request resources within a specific region. Unfortunately there's nothing that can be done for you on Stack Overflow, since this isn't programming related, and there's simply no solution to be had, other than "open a billing ticket."

Comment: Thanks for the response David. This question is not related to my subscription. Its a generic question- ' Do we really have Region for Azure subscription? How does it differ from Azure Region? '

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question, but... Azure subscriptions don't have a region (unless you're talking about Germany & China, which are managed differently). The regions available in a given subscription, to choose from, are Azure regions. Which regions you have available to you are based on several factors. And not all services are available in all Azure regions. Anyway... this is unfortunately an off-topic question here, as the concept of regions is all in the Azure documentation.